Github Actions - ssh handshake error- none public key
i want to deploy ci/cd process automatize. but i got this error:
ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
my deploy yaml file:
name: Deploy İşlemi

on:
  push:
branches:
  - main
  - develop

jobs:
   deploy-main:
runs-on: self-hosted
if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
steps:
  - name: Checkout repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v3

  - name: Setup SSH
    uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.5.3
    with:
      ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}

  - name: SSH Deploy to Main Branch
    uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
    with:
      host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
      username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USERNAME }}
      key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
      port: ${{ secrets.SSH_PORT }}
      script: |
        cd x
        git pull origin main

    deploy-develop:
runs-on: self-hosted
if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/develop'
steps:
  - name: Checkout repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - name: Setup SSH
    uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.5.3
    with:
      ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}

  - name: SSH Deploy to Develop Branch
    uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
    with:
      host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
      username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USERNAME }}
      key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
      port: ${{ secrets.SSH_PORT }}
      script: |
        cd y
        git pull origin develop

i have a server which runs github runner. i create private key files in here and paste content github actions secrets.
but still faces same error.

There is apparently no PublicKey available on the server. The PublicKey must be stored in ~/.ssh/authorised_keys of the user.

No, i have public key in there. i copied it

Can you login to the server from your local computer with the KeyPair and the username? You should test this first.
